# Dotnet webclient timesout but browser works file for json webservice

Tags: c#, .net, json, webclient

I am trying to get the result of the following json webservice https://mtgox.com/code/data/getDepth.php into a string using the following code.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     string data = client.DownloadString("https://mtgox.com/code/data/getDepth.php");
}
```

but it always returns a timeout exception and no data. I plan to use fastjson to turn the response into objects and expected that to be that hard part not the returning of the content of the page.

```
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mtgox.com/code/data/getDepth.php");
  using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
  {
       using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
       {
           string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
       }
   }
```

Also resulted in the same error. Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, strage, this works great for me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
            var result = client.DownloadString("https://mtgox.com/code/data/getDepth.php");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I am specifying a User Agent HTTP header as it seems that the site is expecting it.

Comment: Thanks so much. Can't believe i wasted so much time stuffing around with all the settings and it was the browser setting the whole time.  I should have asked sooner. Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue before. `request.KeepAlive = false` solved my problem. Try this:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mtgox.com/code/data/getDepth.php");
  request.KeepAlive = false;
      using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
      {

           using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
           {
               string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
           }
       }
```