# Exception downloading HTML code

Tags: c#, html, exception, download

I'm trying to download the HTML code of one website using `new WebClient().DownloadString()` but I'm getting this exception all the time:

> The underlying connection was closed. An unexpected error occured on a receive

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you get the error immediately or after a big amount of time?

Comment: HTMLCode = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://something.com")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this question.  You might find the same solution works for you

[Dotnet webclient timesout but browser works file for json webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602990/dotnet-webclient-timesout-but-browser-works-file-for-json-webservice)

Comment: thxxxx, First solution didn't worked but second works great :)